# Solve:$(1-y^2 +\frac{y^4}{x^2})p^2- (2\frac{y}{x})p + \frac{y^2}{x^2}=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, quadratic-forms

I have the differential equation:  $(1-y^2 +\frac{y^4}{x^2})p^2- (2\frac{y}{x})p + \frac{y^2}{x^2}=0$ where $p=\frac{dy}{dx}$

I have solved this up until $\frac{dy}{dx}$, but I am not able to reduce it to an exact differential equation.

Steps until here:

$$\frac{1}{x^2}\Bigl((x^2-x^2 y^2 +y^4)p^2- (2xy)p + y^2\Bigr)=0$$
As $\frac{1}{x^2}$ cannot equal zero,
$$(x^2-x^2 y^2 +y^4)p^2- (2xy)p + y^2=0$$
Applying the quadratic formula:
$$p=\frac{2xy \pm \sqrt{4x^2y^2-4x^2y^2+4x^2y^4-4y^6}}{2(x^2-x^2 y^2 +y^4)}$$
$$p=\frac{xy \pm y^2\sqrt{x^2-y^2}}{x^2-x^2 y^2 +y^4}$$
$$p=\frac{y\Bigl(x \pm y\sqrt{x^2-y^2}\Bigr)}{x^2-y^2(x^2-y^2)}$$
$$p=\frac{y\Bigl(x \pm y\sqrt{x^2-y^2}\Bigr)}{\Bigl(x-y\sqrt{x^2-y^2}\Bigr)\Bigl(x+y\sqrt{x^2-y^2}\Bigr)}$$
Thus,
$$p=\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y}{\Bigl(x-y\sqrt{x^2-y^2}\Bigr)}$$
Or,
$$p=\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y}{\Bigl(x+y\sqrt{x^2-y^2}\Bigr)}$$

From here, we can write the two equations as:
$$xdy-ydx=y\sqrt{x^2 - y^2}dy$$
$$xdy-ydx=-y\sqrt{x^2 - y^2}dy$$

I tried reducing this equation to an exact differential equation, but failed to do so. Kindly help me proceed from here. Thank you!

Comment: You could divide both sides of $$xdy-ydx=y\sqrt{x^2-y^2}dy$$ by $x^2$ and write it as $$d(y/x)=\frac{y\sqrt{x^2-y^2}}{x^2}dy$$ Can you see how to proceed from this point? A similar trick will work for your other equation.

Comment: I got what you've done, but I'm not sure how to simplify the R.H.S...

Comment: Hint: Set $m=y/x$. You'll get a deprapable DE in $m$ and $y$

Comment: Oh! I don't know how I didn't see that. Thanks a lot for your help. Much appreciated :) !!

Answer (score 1):

$$xdy-ydx=-y\sqrt{x^2 - y^2}dy$$
$$yx'-x=y\sqrt{x^2 - y^2}$$
$$\left(\dfrac xy \right)'=\sqrt{\dfrac {x^2}{y^2} -1}$$
$$w'=\sqrt{w^2 -1}$$
Where $w=\dfrac xy$.Then integrate.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was able to solve the question with the help of the comments on my question. Anyways, your help is much appreciated!!

Comment: You're welcome thats great if you solved it. @SmritiSivakumar